# Uniform circular motion on an unbanked road

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

While executing uniform circular motion on a *level* road, the maximum speed has to be such that $v²_{max}$≤ $\mu_s$ $g$ $R$.

Where $v_{max}$ is the maximum possible speed, $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of statics friction, and $g$ and $R$ are the acceleration due to gravity and radius of the circular path executed respectively.

What I want to know is what will happen if I exceed that speed. I know I will *skid*. But for how long? Will I *skid* till I describe a path with a sufficiently big $R$. If yes, how. I'm having trouble visualising the situation.

I'm sorry if the question's *obvious*.

**Edit**

I remembered that I forgot to specify the frame I am *in*. I'm merely an observer, not a passenger of the car. So what would be *my* observations?

Comment: Even if you are not satisfied with the answers, do not try this experiment....

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU That's somewhat obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you negotiate a curve of radius $R$ with a velocity $v$ greater than ${v_{\max }}$. So ${v^2} > {\mu _s}gR$ .
You skid and start sliding across the road.

This is because the *centripetal force* provided by friction is not enough to make you negotiate the curve. While frictional force is providing the necessary centripetal force, it is also preventing the relative motion between the wheels of your car and the road and hence reducing the magnitude of your velocity $v$. (there is friction acting *towards the centre* of the curve as well as *in the direction* of the road)

And while you slide, the distance of your car from the center of the curve also *increases*. While your velocity has *decreased*, the radius of your negotiating curve has *increased*. You continue skidding until your decreased velocity and increased radius satisfy the inequation -  ${v_{new}}^2 \le {\mu _k}g{R_{new}}$.

By the time it satisfied the inequation, if your new radius had exceeded the outer edge of the road, you would have gone off track.

Comment: Do I skid? Or do my tyres turn to make the radius _bigger_. That's all my tyres do right? They decide the radius of the path I describe. The force is provided by friction.

Comment: You definitely skid when $v > \sqrt {{\mu _s}gR} $, because the frictional force exerted is not enough to make you move along the curve. So when you skid, you start going on a path that is **tangential** to the curve, which is at a greater distance than the curve from the center, hence greater than the radius. Your tyres don't turn enough because the frictional force acted on the tyres is just not enough to make it turn at that speed.

Answer (score 0):

If the velocity will exceed the rated velocity then

1. centripetal force will be larger than force by friction hence a pseudo force on the body will make the body move tangential to the circular path
2. Yes you are right that you will move until either you reach sufficiently big R or sufficiently lower velocity due to constant act of friction
3. It might be hard to visualise as most of time our mind doesn't allow to exceed that limit and if we do we ( or vehicle ) tend to fall ( or crash)

Comment: He is analysing the forces in inertial frame that is why it's centripetal force. You are at one point saying centripetal & at the other pseudo force . If centripetal force is larger , larger centripetal force will act. pseudo force acts in a non inertial frame. It might be hard to visualise as most of time our mind doesn't allow to exceed that limit is no answer.

Comment: Appreciate it but will if you could help me with why he can't visualise

Comment: http://www.physics.hku.hk/~phys1055/lectures/chap04.html .....Go to the turning of a car.....

Comment: The force acting tangentially is not a pseudo force, it is again the force of friction preventing the drive wheel from slipping as it rotates. Friction acts radially and tangentially in this situation.

Comment: @sammygerbil If I'm within the safe speeds, the friction will be acting only radially right? Because there will be only radial acceleration?

Comment: No friction acts whenever there is motion in any direction @KunalPawar

Comment: Hmm @Utkarshfutous . But friction is providing me the radial acceleration in case of uniform circular motion right? The net friction is towards the centre?

Comment: No component of net force provide centripetal force that acts along radially

Comment: Why a *pseudo* force? I'm afraid I should have specified my frame. I'm​ an observer. Not a passenger of the car (in my imagination).